# Web server reseting connection even with ports 443 and 80 open

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nginx

I have an nginx server running on my Raspberry Pi. Everything was working fine until I ran a simple `sudo apt upgrade`. It broke up everything. My web server runs well locally since I can access my web pages from devices on my local network. However, when I try to access my web server from external internet (using both IP and DynDNS) on Firefox I get Connection Reset error and with Chrome and curl command I get empty response error. I also tried accessing my web pages using HTTP only (I didn't enforce nginx to use HTTPS) but also doesn't work.

I tried to put my Raspberry Pi in a DMZ, and it worked: I could access my web pages from everywhere. Since I am a bit worried about security I definitely don't want to leave my Pi in DMZ like this.

Turns out if I go back again to port forwarding rules, the error messages show up. So the problem is coming from my router and I don't understand why.

[image: Port Forwarding rules capture]

Shouldn't nginx use ports 80 and 443?

Why is this happening?

Here are some screenshots

[image: Firefox error message]

[image: Chrome error message]

Comment: welcome to SU. what broke? you say you can access from internal LAN. most routers use 22/80/443 for themselves and you can't port forward them. you need to do the same as you did with ssh for the rasp - 922ext->22int, I would avoid well known ports (922 seems to be free). how did you test your port forwarding? you NEED to be outside the LAN to test it, most routers will not trigger the port forwarding rule from inside LAN on the external IP.

Comment: @Zina well at least for my router ports 22, 80 and 443 can be forwarded without any problem so I don't need to change the external ports. I tested my port forwarding simply by putting my Raspberry Pi in a DMZ in which all ports are forwarded.. And when my server was in DMZ, web pages were loading even when accessing from internal IP. Also, like I said, my web server can be accessed from all devices on my local network so the problem definitely comes from port forwarding

Comment: how do you know that port forwarding works for 80,443 if you are not able to access the pi from outside? being able to set it in the port forwarding part of the wouter web config does not mean it will work. have you checked your port forwarding with a port forwarding website? putting a host in DMZ is different then port forwarding, my router for example will expose a host in DMZ only for ports which are NOT in my port forwarding list. I would ask you to eg port forward 4433 to 443 on your pi and test it.

Comment: I know that port forwarding work on these ports because it used to work one month ago before I update my Pi software. I also didn't update my router firmware recently, so I think my problem comes from the pi. So I did try to forward port 4443 (or whatever other port) and my web server worked.... only for the default nginx html page. Note : I used Certbot --nginx to add HTTPS to my domain. (1/2)

Comment: I would also like to mention that some time ago my server was running on Apache and that when I moved to Nginx I simply copy-pasted all my files in /var/www/html. Is it needed to change some .conf files in order for HTTPS to work on these non-default files ? (2/2)